# error in automapper with child type

Tags: c#, automapper

i'm having an error during automapper in win app in c# this row:

```
  config.CreateMap<T432, PROC>()
 .ForMember(d => d.TIPO.COD_TIPO , o => o.MapFrom(s => s.COD_TIPO))
```

the error is : Expression 'd => d.TIPO.COD_TIPO' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.\r\nNome parametro: lambdaExpression"}

where

```
 class T432
 {
    public string COD_TIPO { get; set; }
 }
 class PROC 
 {
    public TIPO_PROC TIPO { get; set; }
 }
 class TIPO_PROC
 {
    public string COD_TIPO { get; set; }
 }
```

how is correct automapper?

thanks in advance

Comment: did the answer I provide help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom type converter as AutoMapper cannot configure "nested" objects and only sets top level properties, take a look at the example on the automapper site https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters

here is the example:

`Mapper.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());`

```
public class DateTimeTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(string source)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDateTime(source);
    }
}
```

This will map a `string` to a `DateTime` object. You can easily substitute your own types and provide any configuration within the `Convert` method.

Answer (score -1):

Brother the correct thing is that Try This

```
config.CreateMap(T432,PROC)().ForMember(d=>d.TIPO, o => o.ResolveUsing(s => new TIPO {COD_TIPO=s.COD_TIPO}));
```

Sorry Use this "<>" instead of () in CreateMap,
like CreateMap<>.